# 'ClientFilter' validation failed: client view is too loose . each client should include one project only

Tags: windows, perforce

I am trying to do same operations that I do with perforce GUI using command line.

When I tried to do `p4 edit` on any file, it said `Client '<host-name>' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.`

So, I tried `p4 client -o <my-workspace-name> | p4 client -i` but this returned:

```
Error in client specification.
'ClientFilter' validation failed:
======================================================
    client view is too loose !!!
    each client should include one project only
======================================================
```

I have no experience of p4 tool. Please help me explain what it means with client view too loose !!!

Comment: I've never seen this error before. Could it be a trigger that your admin has in place? The "Client '<host-name>' unknown" makes me wonder if you have a client set. Try editing your client to include only that to which you need access (e.g., "//depot/this_project/...")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a trigger that your admin has set up.  Based on the error, I surmise that they want you to set up your client's View to only include one project (they want to keep you from syncing down the entire world when you set up your new client).

To create a new client, run:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=your_workspace_name
p4 client
```

and take a look at the form that pops up.  The `View` field defines which part of the depot(s) your client will "see" and operate on.  According to the error message, your admin wants you to restrict this to a single "project" -- I don't know what that means in this context (maybe it means just a single depot, or maybe a single folder in a particular depot?) so you might need to talk to your admin about it, or maybe browse around in the GUI and try to glean from context clues (i.e. names of directories) what that message is referring to.

Just to use a made-up example, if you have a few different depots your default ("loose") View might look like:

```
//depot_one/... //your_workspace_name/depot_one/...
//mumble/... //your_workspace_name/mumble/...
//widgets/... //your_workspace_name/widgets/...
```

and if you want to only map the project `//mumble/core` to your workspace root, you'd change that View to:

```
//mumble/core/... //your_workspace_name/...
```

Comment: It turns out that I just needed to set my client the right way. Doing just "p4 set P4CLIENT=my_workspace_name" worked.

Comment: Yes, just using the workspace that you already have configured correctly is the easiest solution.  :)